# How does Date() constructor return a value

Tags: java, date, constructor

When I call `System.out.println(new Date());` am I not calling the constructor in the class `Date`? Please correct me if I am wrong. So in that case how is it returning value?

Comment: You are, which returns an Object of type `Date` and `println()` is implicitly calling `toString()` on that object.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Just looking at questions on the java tag makes me sad, most of them are at least -1. Do java people really hate questions that much?

Comment: @arynaq: It is _very_ unclear what this question is asking.

Comment: the question was "i know new operator calls constructor and how can constructor return a value". 
Anyways, I now know what happened, thanks to people who cared to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you are indeed calling the constructor for the `Date()` class, and implicitly calling its `toString()` method. If you wanted to know what that method *does*, you'll want to look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

The constructor just grabs the system time in milliseconds (often in tens of milliseconds, evidently) as a `long`, and `toString()` parses it, by referring to the methods available in [`sun.util.calendar.CalendarDate`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/calendar/CalendarDate.java) and then generating a StringBuilder object, which is ultimately what is returned to you.

So while you're calling the constructor for the `Date()` object (and implicitly calling its `toString()` method), under the hood there's quite a bit more going on. If your motivation here is to build your own date parser, you can review the source for the classes involved for guidance, or you can simply make calls to these classes and let them do the work.

Answer (score 3):

It prints a value because you are implicitly invoking the `toString` method of the newly constructed `Date` object.

This is equivalent to the following:

```
Date date = new Date();  
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you are calling Date constructor.  Every time you are using "new" operator, a constructor is called.  You are just not storing the reference to the newly created object, so it will get garbaged collected soon.
So what happens is:

1. Date constructor is called
2. The instance of Date is passed to the println method which takes Object argument
3. println method calls toString() method on the date and gets the string
   representation; prints it
4. method returns, instance of date gets garbaged collected (eventually)

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` is an expression that is a constructor call.

The result of such an expression is guaranteed to be a newly constructed object.  (or an exception)

Comment: eh while true, i think it misses the point of the question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: You are understanding the unclear question differently than I did.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis

I just tested that too. Thanks guys.
import java.io.*;

class outputobj
{
  public outputobj()
  {
    int i;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return "outPutString\n";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(new outputobj());
  }
}

Gives me output :-)